# printing chars and ints

Tags: c++, c, string, char

I have this code in my program but it doesn't print the numbers, but if I was to switch the "i" in the "((char)i)" to any normal character like say 'a', then it would print to the console.

Why doesn't this print to my console?

```
char debugStr[1000];
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        debugStr[i] = ((char)i);
    }
OutputDebugStringA(debugStr);
```

below prints successfully a line of 1000 "a":

```
    char debugStr[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            debugStr[i] = ((char)'a');
        }
    OutputDebugStringA(debugStr);
```

Comment: An `int` doesn't fit into a `char`...

Comment: And in either case your code is undefined, because you completely fill the buffer with data, leaving no place for the terminating NUL that `OutputDebugStringA` requires.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you desire, you want to store the character value of the number?  Or literally '1', '2', '3'?

Comment: oh, I see what you guys are talking about. Then I must change my direction. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: You should decide which language you're using. C and C++ are very different languages (despite the syntactic similarities), and this doesn't look like C++ to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very first character has the value zero.

Presumably, `OutputDebugStringA` interprets its argument as a C-style string: a zero-terminated character sequence. So it will keep printing characters until it finds a zero; in this case, that will happen immediately, so nothing will come out.

The second example gives undefined behaviour: it will trundle off the end of the array and keep going until it either finds a zero-valued byte, or reaches an unreadable memory location and crashes.

Answer (score 3):

In C, strings are null-terminated. Since you are setting the first character to 0, the string is considered empty.

`23` (the number) is something very different than `"23"` (the string).

Answer (score 1):

Probably since you start with 0, you get no output. I'd keep it between 32 <= and <= 127

see the ascii table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Two things, int i starts from 0, which is null byte. which will most likely be the terminating character for a print function. If i starts at nonzero and still doesn't print, then you might have to consider the endianness. In litte-endian, int is read right-to-left, whereas chars are read from left-to-right, so conversion "may" be only looking at the leftmost byte of int.